# Reset ringtone picker preferences

Tags: ringtone, default-applications, handcent-sms

My Samsung Galaxy S2 on Gingerbread was set to use Handcent as the default ringtone picker, and I accidentally changed this back to the built-in ringtone picker. How do I get it to use Handcent again? I went to Handcent, cleared the checkbox and marked it back again, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Handcent app as the default ringtone picker. To set Handcent as default ringtone picker, go to

> Settings | Applications | Manage Applications | All | Android System
>   (Sound picker for SE phones)

Click '**Clear Defaults**' button.

[image: Clear Defaults]

After this, When you are choosing a ringtone, You will be presented with a dialog box asking you to select one of the application as ringtone picker. Enable the **'Use by default for this action'** Check-box and select Handcent. This will set Handcent as your default ringtone picker.

Comment: I couldn't find the sound picker, but I did this for Android System, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

in android 4.1/4.2 etc etc its called "media storage" (the one you clear the defaults of)

ya i did just actually go through the whole list and pick it out of ALL of them .. and OMFG IT WORKED ..

hey, sorry im late, but, people seem to be clicking these defaults and not knowing how to clear them (like me) then they go and search for it and nobody knows ..

im actually kind of thankful that it wasnt something more difficult to find, so .. there you go . . "media storage" on samsung galaxy s2 android 4.1

Answer (score 2):

For those that have Samsung 8 the place to reset the default apps is
Settings|Apps|App Manager|
Go to the Three dots on top right and from the pull-down select Reset app preferences

Answer (score 1):

One workaround would be to temporarily install another app that has a ringtone picker in order to show the ringtone picker selection screen, select Handcent, and remove the temporary app. For example, you can try [Zedge](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.zedge.android).

Comment: Reinstalling Handcent is another option.